# Primefaces datatable frozen columns misallignment

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

We have a data table as shown in the image. There are 3 frozen columns and rest scrollable. The frozen columns are misalligned as shown. If frozen columns attribute is removed, the table looks properly. Any suggestions to solve the problem.

[image: frozen columns misallignemnt]

Answer (score 4):

I have had similar issues in the past with frozen datatable and using many different scripts across different posts I have found the below script works in ALL browsers and does not require you to set a height it will calculate it.  As an added bonus it also triggers a browser event to force the table to resize properly.

```
synchronizeRowsHeight : function() {
   var $leftRows = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-left').find('tr');
   var $rightRows = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right').find('tr');

   $leftRows.each(function(index) {
         var $leftRow = $(this);
         var $leftHeight = $leftRow.innerHeight();
         var $rightRow = $rightRows.eq(index);
         var $rightHeight = $rightRow.innerHeight();

         if ($rightHeight > $leftHeight) {
                $leftRow.innerHeight($rightHeight);
                var diff = $rightHeight - $leftRow.innerHeight();
                if (diff != 0)
                       $leftRow.innerHeight($rightHeight + diff);
         } else if ($rightHeight < $leftHeight) {
                $rightRow.innerHeight($leftHeight);
                var diff = $leftHeight - $rightRow.innerHeight();
                if (diff != 0)
                       $rightRow.innerHeight($leftHeight + diff);
         }
   })

   // fire a resize event to tell the table to repaint
   $(window).trigger('resize');
}
```

Comment: Why not 'fork' p:dataTable in PrimeFaces extensions and make it a 'playground' for new features? I'd be happy to contribute some additional ones (new features).

Comment: I have thought about that.  The problem is that Datatable is such a beast and the JS is pretty huge that I wasn't sure I wanted to tackle maintaining that. Even when I have a Datatable issue I usually report it to PF for Mert to fix as he seems to be the only person making changes to it now.  Even tandraschko usually leaves the datatable bugs alone!

Comment: Can you state what your issue is/was? So I can better try to incorporate this into PF (or fix the underlying issue in the datatable js and/or renderer

Comment: @Kukeltje I think its the same issue as this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2388

Comment: Will this also work with primeng (for Angular)?

Comment: no this is for PrimeFaces JSF only

Answer (score 1):

**Primefaces datatable frozen:**

Frozen datatable has 2 parts left(fixed) and right(dynamic/scrollable)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function synchronizeRowsHeight() {
  //aligning table header row
  var $leftHeaderRow = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-left .ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box tr');
  var $rightHeaderRow = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right .ui-datatable-scrollable-header-box tr');
  $leftHeaderRow.outerHeight(35);//height(px) in int    
  $rightHeaderRow.outerHeight(35);//height(px) in int   

  //aligning table data rows
   var $leftRows = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-left .ui-datatable-scrollable-body tr');
   var $rightRows = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right .ui-datatable-scrollable-body tr');
   $leftRows.each(function (index) {
     var $leftRow = $leftRows.eq(index); 
     var $rightRow = $rightRows.eq(index);
     $rightRow.innerHeight($leftRow.innerHeight());
     $leftRow.innerHeight($rightRow.innerHeight());       
  });   
}
</script>
```

Call the above javascript function from your bean like

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("synchronizeRowsHeight();");
```

Answer (score 0):

We have the same Problem in a similar use case.
As to my knowledge there is no nice solution to this.

The easiest way, as we solved it, is to resize the heights of the smaller tr's and th's every time the datatable  is redrawn (including ajax events like sorting etc.)

Another possible way would be to prevent different heights by e.g. stop the lines from breaking.