# Getting row height as zero in p:dataTable

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using `p:dataTable` with `scrollable="true"` and `frozenColumns="1"`. On page load I am fetching height of all the rows of both the left(Generated) and right(Generated) tables using JavaScript's `height()` method. But I am getting the height as **zero** **on page load** and if I call the method again I get correct heights. Is there is way to fetch the height after the all the rows have correct height? or Should I think of some other way?

Comment: at page load your table doesn't exist, it is added to the html when datatable adds it. add your script at the end of page.

Comment: i have added it at the end of the page. Basically i was trying to solve the following problem, but i am getting height as zero : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109391/primefaces-datatable-frozen-columns-row-heights-mismatch

Comment: Is the table loaded through a separate file via like an Ajax request or something?

Comment: @Binvention yes, the table is loaded on click of a button. Before button click it has property `display : none`

Comment: Then you can only get the height after the table is loaded try putting it in the success handler of the table getting loaded

Comment: @Binvention, but there is no ajax event. on click of button i just change the property to `display : block`.

Comment: So are you checking the height in the click handler after you change display to block

Comment: @Binvention, yes, i am checking the height in click handler.

Comment: Do you happen to be using jquery? My guess is your problem is that it's checking the height before the Dom is updated with jquery there is an easy way to fix that

Comment: @Binvention, yes i can use jQuery.

Comment: If you use the show function on the table rather then change the css then one of the options you have is to run a function once the show is complete (they designed it for animation but it would also work to solve your problem)

Comment: So use show(0,handler function);

Comment: Thanks @Binvention. I checked that i was fetching height before actually making `display : block`. Just changed the order and things worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please create an answer