# Primefaces Datatable frozenHeader and scrollableHeader group, Header height miss match

Tags: primefaces, datatable, frozen-columns

I create data table with prime faces 5.2 
and I use FrozenHaeader and scrollableHeader.

I read it from

> [lost header datatable use frozen column primeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480145/lost-header-datatable-use-frozen-column-primeface/36791035#36791035)

### Problem

Header column height not sync between FrozenHaeader and scrollableHeader
follow picture :
[Datatable frozen column picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOQEt.png)

### My code

```
<p:dataTable var="result"  value="#{reportBRBean.listZone2}" id="dataTb" selectionMode="single" selection="#{reportBRBean.selectedZone}" 
 frozenColumns="3"      scrollable="true" scrollWidth="800"

 rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}" rowKey="#{result.zoneCode}"  >
```

frozenHeader :

```
<p:columnGroup type="frozenHeader"  >
<p:row>
<p:column  rowspan="4" width="20" style="background-color: #00CCCC !important;"/>
<p:column  rowspan="4" headerText="#{msg['br1.zone.lb.zone']}" width="140" style="background-color: #00CCCC !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="4" headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.birth.certificate']}" width="110" style="background-color: #00CCCC !important;"/>
</p:row></p:columnGroup>
```

scrollableHeader :

```
<p:columnGroup type="scrollableHeader"  >
<p:row>
<p:column colspan="10"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.inform.birth']}" width="900" style="background-color: #00CCCC !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="4" headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.percent.inform.birth.all']}" width="100" style="background-color: #ffcc66 !important;"/>
<p:column colspan="10" headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.noinform.birth']}" width="900" style="background-color: #00CCCC !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="4" headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.percent.noinform.birth.all']}" width="100" style="background-color: #ffcc66 !important;"/>
</p:row>
<p:row>
<p:column colspan="4"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.inform.within15']}" style="background-color: #ff99ff !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="3"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.percent.inform.within15']}" style="background-color: #ffff99 !important;"/>
<p:column colspan="4"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.inform.over15']}" style="background-color: #ff99ff !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="4"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.percent.inform.over15']}" style="background-color: #ffff99 !important;"/>
<p:column colspan="4"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.noinform.within15']}" style="background-color: #ff99ff !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="3"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.percent.noinform.within15']}" style="background-color: #ffff99 !important;"/>
<p:column colspan="4"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.amount.noinform.over15']}" style="background-color: #ff99ff !important;"/>
<p:column rowspan="4"  headerText="#{msg['br2.lb.percent.noinform.over15']}" style="background-color: #ffff99 !important;"/>
</p:row>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please, introduce and explain your problem.

Comment: Working solution for PF 6.2 and all browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887963/primefaces-datatable-frozen-columns-misallignment/51306819#51306819

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by use javascript.

I call javascript after(oncomplete) data table generates.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         /*<![CDATA[*/

        function synchronizeRowsHeight() {


            var $rows = $(document.getElementById('doctorForm:resultDoctorService_frozenThead')).find('tr');
                        $rows.each(function(index) {
                            var $row = $(this);
                            $row.innerHeight($(document.getElementById('doctorForm:resultDoctorService_scrollableThead')).outerHeight());
                        });
                    }
                    // ]]>
</script>
```

***doctorForm:resultDoctorService_frozenThead***

"**doctorForm**" forms ID

"**resultDoctorService**" data table ID

"**frozenThead**" columns group type