# When ajax oncomplete, jquery does not working, Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using this [**plugin**](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html) for fixed table columns on my **Primefaces** project. It works partly.

```sh
primefaces v6.1
jQuery v1.7.1
```

Works when;

- `p:dataTable` --> `<p:ajax event="page"(and rowSelect) oncomplete"..." />`
- `window.onresize` and window load
- refresh page (F5)

Not works when;

- `<p:commandButton oncoplete="..." />` this button `ubdate` a form.

I share the details of the project below.

Outline xhtml;

```html
+ <p:tab>
+-   <h:form id="myForm" >
+--     <p:panelGrid>
+---         <div>
+----            <p:commandButton update=":myForm" oncomplete="load()">
+--     <p:dataTable>
           ...
```

Outline script;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    load(); 
});

function load(){
    $("div.ui-datatable-tablewrapper").find('table').tableHeadFixer({
        left: 2
    });     
}
```

As i said, it works for dataTable ajax event.

**But** when commandButton clicked, it works only for headers(`thead`), does not work for body(`tbody`).

**How can I fix ?**

To be more understandable, look at gif for two columns, first of all it works, but change datatable by button it does not work and i am resizing window it works.
[image]

Comment: 1: **always** post version info. 2: **always** post a [mcve] for things that are not working. 3: PrimeFaces has fixed headers in it, why an additional plugin?

Comment: I know that dataTable has attributes. But if I use frozen attributes, datatabe not aligned. About that, I researched but I couldn't find what I wanted.

Comment: So you want us to find a fix for a workaround that is not working instead of helping with a real fix for the existing functionality?

Comment: For existing functionality, i researched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887963/primefaces-datatable-frozen-columns-misallignment) question. But it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: There are a few questions about this, but none of them fix the problem. So I looked for a workaround.

Comment: Great, 1: like [ask] states, you should normally post this kind of info in the question from the start. 2: In addition, version info is still missing, as is a [mcve] (the functionality works in the PF showcase). 3: The tiltle is effectively wrong. jquery IS working in the oncomplete. It is called and does not crash. And the question is 5 years old... for an even older version of PF. Things have changed since then.

Comment: Please see the upvotes on my comments. Unless you create a [mcve], **_NO-ONE_** can help you. And if you see the upvote on my second comment, the chance of other willing to help with a workaround instead of helping with a fix for the real issue (after you tried PF 7 or even better PF 8) is not high... We **are** willing to help, with the **real** issue on the plain PF code...without a plugin. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for NOT creating a [mcve] and thanks for NOT posting the original issue so we can NOT solve it for others (whatever it is)

Comment: Where are my mistakes? Isn't the code minimal and understandable anyway? I couldn't fully understand about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Can you exemplify on my post?

Comment: no, read about the [mcve] copy, paste the code above in a new empty project, does it run? No, so it is not reproducable. It is not complete and it is less than minimal... And does it work if the tab is not there? No? Then the tab should not be there... Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed with **primefaces** real issue. When commandButton complete ajax request, run any js function and this function calls `p:remoteCommand`.

```html
<p:commandButton oncomplete="reload()" />
<p:remoteCommand name="remote" oncomplete="load()" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    load(); 
});
function reload(){
    remote();
}
function load(){
    $("div.ui-datatable-tablewrapper").find('table').tableHeadFixer({
        left: 2
    });     
}
```

Comment: This is NOT the PrimeFaces **real** issue fix but a fix for a not a workaround that should not be needed. Due to a lack of an [mcve] it is even impossible to see why this fixes this with a **double** ajax call. People should **NOT** attempt to solve a real original issue of the fixed headers not working.

Comment: If you feel you've ran into an issue, it's not the best idea to create a workaround. Report an error at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces and if possible fix it yourself and provide a pull request.